# Tenant creation error- Locale cannot be null

Tags: deepsecurity

This is my first time posting to stack overflow, thank you for your patience!

I am trying to create a new tenant in deep security and am getting this
error:

```
An exception occurred when calling TenantsApi.create_tenant: (400)
Reason: 
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1;mode=block', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache,no-store', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'X-DSM-Version': 'Deep Security/11.2.225', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '44', 'Date': 'Mon, 17 Dec 2018 23:39:16 GMT', 'Connection': 'close'})
HTTP response body: {"message":"Account locale cannot be null."}
```

**Am I missing a locale option or something else?**

```
#import, setup, authentication related info removed

tenant = deepsecurity.Tenant()
api_version = 'v1'
bypass_tenant_cache = False
confirmation_required = False
asynchronous = False

def create_tenant(client, configuration, api_version, api_exception, account_name):

    # Define the administrator account
    admin = client.Administrator()
    admin.username = "TenantAdmin"
    admin.password = "Pas$w0rd"
    admin.email_address = "example@email.com"
    admin.receive_notifications = "false"
    admin.role_id = 1
    admin.locale = "en_US"

    tenant = client.Tenant(administrator=admin)
    modules = client.Tenant.modules_visible = ["anti-malware", "firewall", "intrusion-prevention"]
    tenant.modules_visible = modules
    tenant.name = 'api-woot'
    tenant.locale = "en-US"
    tenant.description = "Test tenant."

    try:
        tenants_api = client.TenantsApi(client.ApiClient(configuration))
        return tenants_api.create_tenant(tenant, api_version, confirmation_required=False)

    except api_exception as e:
        return "Exception: " + str(e)
try:
        api_response = api_instance.create_tenant(tenant, api_version, bypass_tenant_cache=bypass_tenant_cache, confirmation_required=confirmation_required, asynchronous=asynchronous)
        pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
        print("An exception occurred when calling TenantsApi.create_tenant: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: You are using the tenant as the first parameter of the function call, but it needs to be a variable that represents the api module. You can see an example of this here: https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_2/first-steps-for-deep-security-developers?platform=on-premise#use-an-http-client (I work on Deep Security BTW)

Comment: I can't seem to upvote your comment but this was also the issue, Thank you Scott!

Comment: any time! Good luck with your project

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a minor issue with the local options to me.  You've got "en_US" (underscore) for the tenant locale, and "en-US" (dash) for the administrator locale.

Based on the API Reference, it looks like it should be "en-US" (dash) for both. See: https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_2/api-reference?platform=on-premise#operation/createTenant

Hope that solves this error for you.
(FYI, I work at Trend Micro)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else browsing: Here is my code that is working.  The api site did not make it clear enough for me to add variables for tenant and administrator so it took me a while     to figure out

here are the 2 articles I used for reference:

https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_2/api-reference?platform=aws#operation/createTenant

https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_2/create-and-manage-tenants?platform=on-premise

you need to add your own setup and authentication pieces at the top then:

```
# Initialization
# Set Any Required Values
api_instance = deepsecurity.TenantsApi(deepsecurity.ApiClient(configuration))
tenant = deepsecurity.Tenant()
tenant.locale = "en-US"
tenant.name = "api-woot"
tenant.description = "test tenant"

admin = deepsecurity.Administrator()
admin.username = "tenantadmin"
admin.role_id = 1
admin.password = "Pas$w0rd"
admin.full_name = "bob admin"
admin.email_address = "a@email.com"
admin.receive_notifications = "false"
tenant.administrator = admin

api_version = 'v1'
bypass_tenant_cache = False
confirmation_required = False
asynchronous = False

try:
        api_response = api_instance.create_tenant(tenant, api_version, bypass_tenant_cache=bypass_tenant_cache, confirmation_required=confirmation_required, asynchronous=asynchronous)
        pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
        print("An exception occurred when calling TenantsApi.create_tenant: %s\n" % e)
```